# ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding 'true' while converting IOB to JSONL for SpaCy

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to convert IOB format text file to SpaCy format with start and end index for each token.

I run this code:

```
python -m spacy convert test_IOB.txt out --converter jsonl --lang English
```

I got error:

```
ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding 'true'
```

My input data looks like this:

```
the O
r O
/ O
p O
( O
years O
) O
ratio O
of O
the O
sand O
is O
16 O
. O

chiaramonte O
, O
l. O
2008 O
, O
geomechanical O
characterization O
and O
reservoir O
simulation O
of O
a O
co O
sequestration O
project O
in O
a O
mature O
ofield O
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `--converter json` option, but your input file isn't in `json` format.

You should be using `--converter ner` for the input you're using.

> **ner**
>
> NER with IOB/IOB2 tags, one token per line with columns separated by whitespace. The first column is the token and the final column is the IOB tag. Sentences are separated by blank lines and documents are separated by the line -DOCSTART- -X- O O. Supports CoNLL 2003 NER format. [See sample data](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/examples/training/ner_example_data).